# Writing a diagonal of a matrix (2D list) function

Tags: python, matrix

I want to write a function that accepts one argument, a square 2D matrix, and returns the diagonal of the entered matrix from the interactive window of IDLE.

I have tried several ways but whenever I input a matrix (1 to 16 in a 4 × 4) I get a `TypeError` saying `4 positional arguments but 5 were given`.

I have messed around with it trying to use `input()` to be able to enter the matrix I want but I still get the same error.

This is what I want to be able to do:

```
>>> m1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
>>> diagonal(m1)
[1, 6, 11, 16]
```

How would I go about this? I have also seen a lot of posts using Numpy but I am not entirely sure if it is allowed to use on this assignment.

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please postyour _several ways_ as [mcve], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: With numpy, you just need to prepend `np` as `np.diagonal(m1)` where numpy imported as `np`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) is very convenient here with a square matrix because it will give you the proper indexes as you loop through your arrays. You can use it in a comprehension to get both the correct index and the correct matrix.

```
def diagonal(mat):
    return [el[i] for i, el in enumerate(mat)]

m1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]

diagonal(m1)
>> [1, 6, 11, 16]
```

Comment: If I use enumerate, wouldn't the start HAVE to be equal to 0 though? And, I actually had something similar to this, except I added both i and j for columns and rows

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def diagonal(m1):
    n = len(m1)
    l = []
    for i in range(n):
        l.append(m1[i][i])

    return l

m1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
print(diagonal(m1))
```